# MATLAB matrix^-0.5 equivalent in Python

Tags: python, matlab, matrix

I suggested it could be

```
 np.linalg.inv(np.sqrt(matrix))
```

but having compared result with MATLAB I saw big difference:

This was in MATLAB

```
 0.2622   -0.0828   -0.0708
-0.0828    0.2601   -0.0792
-0.0708   -0.0792    0.2664
```

And this was in Python:

```
 0.8607   -0.4417   -0.3536
-0.4417    0.8967   -0.4158
-0.3536   -0.4158    0.8525
```

Input was

```
34.502193  27.039107  24.735074
27.039107  36.535737  26.069613
24.735074  26.069613  32.798584
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "matrix" class in python. From your code it looks you're talking about `numpy`.

A possible gotcha for matlab users is that in `numpy` array operations are *elementwise* by default, and if you want matrix operations, you need to request them: `np.dot` for matrix multiplications, `np.linalg.inv` for inversion etc.

`np.linalg.inv(np.sqrt(a))` first takes the square root *of each element* of `a`, and then inverts the result in the linear algebra sense. I suspect this is not what you meant to mean.

If you meant elementwise operations, i.e. you wanted to raise each element to power `-1/2`, then like @Benoit_11 suggests, use
`1 / np.sqrt(a)`.

If what you want is actually a linear algebra operation, then use [`scipy.linalg.sqrtm`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/linalg.html)

```
In [14]: a
Out[14]: 
array([[ 34.502193,  27.039107,  24.735074],
       [ 27.039107,  36.535737,  26.069613],
       [ 24.735074,  26.069613,  32.798584]])
In [15]: from scipy.linalg import sqrtm

In [16]: sq = sqrtm(a)

In [17]: np.dot(sq, sq) - a
Out[17]: 
array([[  4.97379915e-14,   4.97379915e-14,   2.84217094e-14],
       [  5.32907052e-14,   6.39488462e-14,   4.61852778e-14],
       [  3.55271368e-14,   3.19744231e-14,   3.55271368e-14]])
```

Comment: Very nice!  Even love the different comparison. +1.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like using Python you calculated the inverse of the square root of the matrix (sounds weird sorry) instead of raising the matrix to the power -0.5.

For instance, running this command with Matlab I get your output with python:

```
m = [34.502193  27.039107  24.735074
27.039107  36.535737  26.069613
24.735074  26.069613  32.798584]


A = inv(sqrt(m))

A =

    0.8608   -0.4417   -0.3537
   -0.4417    0.8967   -0.4159
   -0.3537   -0.4159    0.8525
```

versus this:

```
B = m^(-.5)

B =

    0.2622   -0.0828   -0.0708
   -0.0828    0.2601   -0.0792
   -0.0708   -0.0792    0.2664
```

For the correct Python code please look at @ev-br's answer

Beware that there is such a thing as the matrix square root, which for a matrix M is defined as:

```
A*A = M
```

and does not correspond at all to the square root of each element in the matrix M taken individually. The matrix square root is obtained in Matlab using the [sqrtm](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sqrtm.html) function and is equivalent to `m^(.5)`.

Comment: `np.power` acts elementwise

Comment: @Benoit_11 I would recommend you to clarify this answer. I would be good to clarify that `sqrt` in matlab is not the matrix square root, but that `m^(0.5)` is. Though it is said in another answer you cannot count this answer to remain forever. It is more likely that a user thinks that `m^(0.5)` is the same as `sqrt` and is unaware of the mystical matrix square root.

Comment: Yes good point @patrik I'll clarify that thanks for pointing out.